# How to limit total number of posts in wp query loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop

I want to show 5 posts per page but limit total number of posts being resulted in a loop.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'paged' => $paged
);
```

Suppose, I have 100 posts and the above query args will display 5 posts per page and I can see 20 pages. So, how can I limit the total number of posts being resulted so that in my condition it would only show 3 pages? I'm not needing exactly 3 pages to show but wanted to limit the total post like 25 posts, 23 posts. So, if I wanted to limit 12 posts then I can see 5 posts on first page, 5 posts on second page and remaining 2 posts on last page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`found_posts` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/found_posts) to alter the number of posts WordPress reports finding from a query.

```
add_filter( 'found_posts', 'wpd_found_posts', 10, 2 );
function wpd_found_posts( $found_posts, $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return 25;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it seems not working as expected. I just tried 'post_per_page'=>4 and using the filter returned 7 and it should show 3 posts on second page but showing 4 posts.

Comment: have you verified the filter is applied? you need to change the conditions in the function above to target the query you want it applied to.

Comment: yes. if it was not being applied the pagination wouldn't have shown just 2 pages.

Comment: I have not encountered this issue. I'm unable to test at the moment, I will have to get back to you once I can.

Comment: you are right, the filter doesn't seem to work as I remember it. I think you will need to use it in combination with `post_limits` filter to force it to truncate the query results along with the number of posts it reports finding.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with post_limits? I've tried a lot but got not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `post_limits` hook with a priority of 2...

```
function my_posts_limit( $limit, $query ) {
  return 'LIMIT 0, 25';
}
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'my_posts_limit', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Sorry. It's also not working... shows 25 posts on per page.

Comment: You still need to have ` 'posts_per_page' => 5` in your query.

Comment: I have. But doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[post_limits](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_limits)

```
/**
 * Limit the main query search results to 25.
 *
 * We only want to filter the limit on the front end of the site, so we use
 * is_admin() to check that we aren't on the admin side.
 *
 * We also only want to filter the main query, so we check that this is it
 * with $query->is_main_query().
 *
 * Finally, we only want to change the limit for searches, so we check that
 * this query is a search with $query->is_search().
 *
 * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_limits
 * 
 * @param string $limit The 'LIMIT' clause for the query.
 * @param object $query The current query object.
 *
 * @return string The filtered LIMIT.
 */
function wpcodex_filter_main_search_post_limits( $limit, $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && ($query->is_search() || $query->is_home()) ){
        return 'LIMIT 0, 25';
    }

    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'wpcodex_filter_main_search_post_limits', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the post limit in two ways:

```
1) wp-admin > Settings > Reading

2) By passing the argument query 'numberposts' => 5
```

Comment: Great! But I need to do through coding as I'm building custom page.

Comment: And I already tried with 'numberposts' and didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Use the **'numberposts'** parameter...

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'numberposts' => 25,
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'paged' => $paged
);
```

[Exemple at the Developer's Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#user-contributed-notes)

Comment: I think it's deprecated that's why I'm not getting working...

Comment: `numberposts` is the same as `posts_per_page`, they do the same thing.

Comment: I see @BhojendraNepal. You are right. Then Try  **'showposts'** instead.

Comment: @Gonzoarte 'showposts' also not working.

Comment: Ok.. See my other solution using the **'post_limits'** filter.